# How does the auto-free()ing work when I use functions like mktemp()?

Tags: iphone, c

Greetings,

I'm using `mktemp()` (iPhone SDK) and this function returns a `char *` to the new file name where all "X" are replaced by random letters.

What confuses me is the fact that the returned string is automatically `free()`d. How (and when) does that happen? I doubt it has something to do with the Cocoa event loop. Is it automatically freed by the kernel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please consider `mkstemp` instead, if it is available (in `<unistd.h>` or `<stdlib.h>` usually). Typically, you call `mkstemp`, and it returns a file descriptor on which you call `unlink`. This prevents many attacks and race conditions, especially since typical `mktemp` implementations return a previsible name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mktemp just modifies the buffer you pass in, and returns the same poiinter you pass in, there's no extra buffer to be free'd.

That's at least how the OSX [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/mktemp.3.html) describes it(I couldn't find documentation for IPhone) , and the posix manpage (although the example in the posix [manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mktemp.html) looks to be wrong, as it pass in a pointer to a string literal - possibly an old remnant, the function is also marked as legacy - use mkstemp instead. The OSX manpage specifically mention that as being an error).

So, this is what will happen:

```
char template[] = "/tmp/fooXXXXXX";
char *ptr;
if((ptr = mktemp(template)) == NULL) {
   assert(ptr == template); //will be true, 
                           // mktemp just return the same pointer you pass in
}
```

Comment: I noticed that bug in the documentation, too. It does not really modify the pointer I pass in, but instead returns a different one. This is basically why I was confused, as I never really have to free() the returned pointer.

Comment: @badcat: if you're still not convinced, try calling it a couple times and seeing if the returned pointer is always the same: that would confirm it is an internal static buffer as per my answer - which is consistent with your observation that the pointer returned differs from the one you provide the function and my understanding of the man page.  The input is just a template showing where in the filename you want a unique number substituted.  Anyway, Alexandre's comment is on the money - better to avoid a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

If it's like the cygwin function of the same name, then it's returning a pointer to an internal static character buffer that will be overwritten by the next call to mktemp().  On cygwin, the mktemp man page specifically mentions _mktemp_r() and similar functions that are guaranteed reentrant and use a caller-provided buffer.